# how to exclude js form mediarox pagespeed

Tags: magento-1.8

I have implemented pagespeed from mediarox.

Now i want to exclude jquery.min.js from the list, but in the documentation there it is nowhere mentioned how to do this.
how can i exclude only particulate js form list ?